# Domain Registrar Out of Business - Renewing Domain

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar

About a year ago, I registered a domain name with KalyHost, [who has gone out of business](https://www.kalyhost.com/index.html). It seems to have left me in limbo with how I am now to go about renewing my domain name, which expires in 3 days.

I notice in the who-is information, there the entry `Sponsoring Registrar: Key-Systems`. Can anyone advise what my next steps need to be? Do I need to contact this sponsoring registrar to transfer my domain to another party? Who actually holds the registration for the domain now?

Comment: [What is a sponsoring registrar?](http://serverfault.com/questions/461780/what-is-sponsoring-registrar)

Comment: Based on the link that @Rob provided, I would call them tomorrow.

Comment: This is a fairly common problem, and leaving it so close to renewal date to renew or work out a renewal issue is really asking for trouble :P

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to contact the sponsoring registrar and request the Auth Code of your Domain if you have no intentions to renew the Domain with the sponsoring registrar.

Comment: 3 days is not enough time to do this

Comment: If i didnt confused something here the company url is key-systems.net - their domain retail branch is domaindiscount24.com (support@domaindiscount24.com ) | https://www.key-systems.net/en/contact has phone contact and email contact on it - the rest seems to be on you

Comment: domaindiscount24.com site is available in english too, upper right corner language flag. 3 DAys should be much enough to sort it out.